# Найти сумму разностей всех элементов в упорядоченном массиве

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, java

*Добрый вечер, Уважаемые хэшкодовцы!*

Предлагаю немного подумать над оптимальным решением такой вот задачки: 
**нужно найти сумму разностей всех элементов в упорядоченном массиве.**

Поясню на примере: у нас есть массив [-3 5 10], тогда сумма разностей всех его элементов будет = (5+3) + (10+3) + (10-5) = 26

Естественно, самый простой алгоритм, который приходит в голову, это:

```
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length()-1; i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j <= arr.length()-1; j++) {
                sum += arr[j] - arr[i];
            }
```

Но как вы понимаете, он в то же время и самый медленный... Нужно что-то более оптимальное! Какие будут мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: Разность не коммутативная операция. Вы наверное имели ввиду (-3-5) + (-3-10) + (5-10) = -26?

Comment: Нет, суммируются именно разности "следующих" элементов с "предыдущим" - так, как я описал в примере.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать за один проход.

Пусть наша последовательность `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ..., `a[n-1]`. Мысленно выпишем все разности:

```
a[1] - a[0]
a[2] - a[0]
...
a[n-1] - a[0]
a[2] - a[1]
...
```

Подсчитаем, сколько раз у нас входит `a[i]` с плюсом, а сколько — с минусом для произвольного `i`. Выпишем те разности, в которых фигурирует `a[i]`:

```
a[i] - a[0]
a[i] - a[1]
...
a[i] - a[i-1]
a[i+1] - a[i]
a[i+2] - a[i]
...
a[n-1] - a[i]
```

Мы видим, что с плюсом оно входит ровно `i` раз, а с минусом — `(n-1) - (i+1) + 1 = n - i - 1` раз. Получается, для `a[i]` надо взять коэффициент `i - n + i + 1 = 2 * i - n + 1`.

Решение:

```
long sum = 0, n = arr.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum += (2 * i - n + 1) * arr[i];
```

Comment: Превосходный ответ!

Comment: @Rams666: спасибо!

Comment: Ответ @a_gura появился практически одновременно, и содержит по сути то же вычисление.

Answer (score 7):

Если выписать сумму, как функцию от n-парметров, то получим (n1 - n0) + (n2 - n0) + (n2 - n1). Видно, что каждый элемент повторяется несколько раз как есть и несколько раз, как обратная по знаку величина. Отсюда решение за один проход по массиву:

```
    int[] arr = new int[]{-3, 5, 10};
    int m = arr.length;
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        res += arr[i] * i - arr[i] * (m - (i + 1));
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```